# Can't get vertical alignment working on custom ViewGroup

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-linearlayout

I've have the following class, which extendes the ViewGroup class.

I indicate that I want the text aligned 'BOTTOM | RIGHT' which works fine if the Button is in a LinearLayout, but in my custom derivation, it only takes into account the 'RIGHT' parameter.

I have massively simplified my class to make it easier to read.

Is there something obvious I'm missing?

Thanks
Rich

```
public class LayoutManager extends ViewGroup
{
    private Button b1;
    public LayoutManager(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle)
    {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
        LocalInit(context);
    }

    public LayoutManager(Context context, AttributeSet attrs)
    {
        super(context, attrs);
        LocalInit(context);
    }

    public LayoutManager(Context context)
    {
        super(context);
        LocalInit(context);
    }
    private void LocalInit(Context context)
    {
        b1=new Button(context);
        b1.setText("hello button 1");
        b1.setGravity(Gravity.BOTTOM | Gravity.RIGHT);
        super.addView(b1);
    }
    @Override
    protected void onLayout(boolean changed, int l, int t, int r, int b)
    {
        b1.layout(100, 100, 300, 300);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to use [`View.measure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#measure%28int,%20int%29) to tell your `Button` that it will be 200 x 200 regardless of how big it wants to be. Add this to `LayoutManager`:

```
@Override
protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
    super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
    b1.measure(MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(200, MeasureSpec.EXACTLY), MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(200, MeasureSpec.EXACTLY));
}
```